# ff-find-other-file

Tags: find-file

works well, particularly after custom defining additional file type pairs with

```lisp
(defvar my-cpp-other-file-alist '(("\\.cpp\\'" (".hpp" ".cuh"))
                                  ("\\.hpp\\'" (".cpp"".cu"))
                                  ("\\.cuh\\'" (".cu" ".cpp"))
                                  ("\\.cu\\'" (".cuh" ".hpp"))
                                  ("\\.c\\'" (".h"))
                                  ("\\.h\\'" (".c"))))

(setq-default ff-other-file-alist 'my-cpp-other-file-alist)
```

However, it does not switch files when point in on include directive in c/cpp files. What is the setting to always ignore the content under point in this context?

Answer (score 1):

`M-x describe-function RET ff-find-other-file` gives the necessary info. There is custom variable `ff-ignore-include` which should control this, however it seems like it has no effect...

`ff-find-other-file` also has an ignore-include argument and with that it seems to work. So you could use something like:

```lisp
(defun my-ff-find-other-file ()
  (interactive)
  (ff-find-other-file nil t))
```

Comment: I know of this variable, it does not work as expected though

Comment: Strange. Does it work when you use the ignore-include argument of `ff-find-other-file` directly then?

Comment: by directly you mean invoking it via M-x?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain.

Comment: Looking at the code of `ff-find-other-file` explains that, as it calls `(let ((ff-ignore-include ignore-include)) (ff-find-the-other-file in-other-window))` using its `ignore-include` argument (which is always `nil` for interactive calls).  In fact all three commands in that library force the value of `ff-ignore-include`, as `ff-get-other-file` binds it to `t` and `ff-find-other-file-other-window` calls `ff-find-other-file` with the `ignore-include` argument set to `nil`.  I suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug` to improve the documentation about this.

Comment: As such, the suggested custom command in this answer looks like the right way to go.